# Convergence behaviour of Quadratic Variation of Brownian Motion

Tags: brownian-motion, quadratic-variation

Let $(B_{t_i})_{t_i \in [0, t]}$ be a Brownian Motion process and $Q_n(t) := \sum^{n}_{i=1} (\Delta_i B) ^2$ where $\Delta_i B = B_{t_i} - B_{t_{i-1}}$.

How is it that $Q_n(t) := \sum^{n}_{i=1} (\Delta_i B) ^2$ converges to $t$ in mean-square but for a given sample path $\omega \in \Omega$, we have that $Q_n(t)$ does not converge to any number?

What is actually happening to $Q_n(t)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$? Is it oscillating around $t$?

Comment: How do you know Qn does not converge for a given sample path?

Comment: The statement is made in the book "Elementary Stochastic Calculus with Finance in view" by Mikosch on page 98. You may have to find a suitable choice of partition though

Comment: As you increase n, a sample path's Qn might look very much like a convergent sequence interspersed with infinitely many outliers and the outliers becoming sparser and sparser as n goes out to infinity. Just a guess.

Comment: That's very nice. Does this not satisfy the typical definition of pointwise convergence? Or we can't guarantee that all of the next $Q_m$ after some $Q_N$ will be within $\epsilon$ of t?

Comment: Right it could be the latter if there are infinitely many outliers so there is no point wise convergence.